# Gizmo (manipulator) is missing for some reason

Tags: interface, gizmo

I have a problem with gizmo 
(I am not sure what it called but it is the three arrows of axes when you scale, rotate, move).

it disappears sometimes and I can't get it back unless I open a new project. Can please some one help me with that?

I am using Blender 2.8.
When I press Ctrl+Space the show gizmo box is checked.

Comment: the gizmo only shows if you are using one of the translate tools.  you can find them on the tool bar (left part of the screen, if it's not there, press **t**)  is that your problem, or is it something else?

Comment: do you have the code boxes on on purpose?

Comment: it is something else / no I don't , thanks for trying

Comment: when the gizmo disappears, do the selection outlines and the camera and lights still show?

Comment: it was frustrating my friend , I just figured it out why and it was very simple .. I was hitting the spacebar key by accident and the timeline was playing and i wasnt able to do anything until i figured that it moving by frames from the info top left while it is playing .. thank you for your help

Comment: glad you found your issue.  :)

Comment: @mhmadSy the same here! Thank you. But damn - it's so unobvious that animation mode is on! I wish Blender team made it more visually obvious - like chaning background, etc.

Answer (score 9):

I was clicking Space bar by accident and i didn't realize it is going frame by frame until i saw the info datum that shows top left ... Fixed by clicking the space key

Comment: This is what happened to me. If you're in modeling 'mode' and you don't have the timeline under your 3d viewport, you can tell this is what's going on because there's a number in parenthesis constantly counting up, then starting over in the top left. (It's the current frame number)

Comment: man that was driving me crazy. i never use animation should just repurpose the space bar

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue myself.

1. Gizmo size is determined by going to preferences> viewport> gizmo size.
2. There is an icon and drop down menu that controls gizmos, and you must check move, rotate, and scale in order to see them.

Beside the *Overlays* popover, located in the *3D View Header*, the icon sort of looks like a bow and arrow.

[image: viewport gizmos menu]

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem and I was able to fix it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>. Must've accidentally hit it trying to switch to walk navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have something selected in order to see the gizmo, but I guess you know that. If you've accidentally moved the origin of the object to somewhere else out of sight, that could be a cause of an apparently disappeared gizmo.  The gizmo appears over the origin.  Try typing Shift Control Alt C, then go to Origin to Geometry and see if that helps. That's the hotkey for Blender 2.79 at least. If it's not the right hotkey in 2.8, go to the Tools tab when in object mode and Set Origin should be there.

Comment: this was helpful thank you I didn't think of that but the object do scale , move and rotate from the center , the Geometry of the object is in the center .. I don't think this hotkey works for 2.8 . thank you @Susan

Comment: I'm in 2.83 and those hot keys didn't work, for those who were curious.

Answer (score 2):

When You lock Your location in Transform panel the gizmo is switching off...
[image]

Don't know is it helpful but it helped me...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  Turns out my pivot point was switched to 3d cursor somehow.  I flipped it back to individual origins and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are not animating by accident. Look at the lower part of your UI there might be a little bar that says anim player that might be it. Simply close the timeline and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I could see my gizmo on the original screen but not in my split screen. Silly me. There’s a button at the top of the screen that turns it on or off. Looks like a bow and arrow.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138972)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an active move tool not a tweak?

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check what tool is active in the toolbar.  For me, the gizmo doesn't show when the Measure tool is active.